# How to used a for loop to determine the set of index?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I trying to make a program that uses the for loop to calculate the set of index D. But I have a problem because the length of index are not the same.

Example:

```
z = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]

v(1,:) = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
v(2,:) = [0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
v(3,:) = [0 0 1 0 1 1 0]
v(4,:) = [0 0 0 1 0 1 1]

v(1,:) = find(v(1,:)~=z);
v(2,:) = find(v(2,:)~=z);
v(3,:) = find(v(3,:)~=z);
v(4,:) = find(v(4,:)~=z);

we obtain :
D(1,:) = [1 5];
D(2,:) = [2 5 6];
D(3,:) = [3 5 6 7];
D(4,:) = [4 6];
```

Code :

```
for aa = 1:4
    D(aa,:) = [find(v(aa,:)~=z)];
end
```

not work because `length(D(1,:))~=length(D(2,:))~=length(D(3,:))`

How I can use a loop to determine set of index D?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be using `cell` like the following:

```
 for aa = 1:4
     D{aa} = [find(v(aa,:)~=z)];
 end
```

Comment: Thanks you, it works. But I have to use D to calculate minimum, have you another solution to propose me other than the use of cell?

Comment: My pleasure. You can iterate over `cell` like matrix. Also, you can ask your question in details over `cell` in another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the matrix `D`, but initialize it beforehand like:

```
D = ones(size(v)) + length(z)
```

Then fill it like:

```
for ii = 1:size(z,1)
    D(ii,v(ii,:)~=z) = find(v(ii,:)~=z);
end
```

Notice, I added the `length of v` to the matrix of ones, such that you are sure that the predefined numbers in the matrix are larger than any index, hence the `min()` will not freak out.